# JWT authentication based on the Parameter in Multi-tenant Asp.net Core web site

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, multi-tenant

I am using JWT based authentication in my .net core 2.1 web site. Currently this works fine. Now, I have to make one API multi-tenant and each tenant will have it's own secret key. The tenant Id will be passed as parameter to the API.

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("tenant/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetInfo(string id)
        {
        }
```

Each tenant will sign the JWT and will add to Authorization header. I am not able to think of a way to change  IssuerSigningKey based on the parameter.  I tried following:

1. Validating the JWT inside the API by making it [`AllowAonymus`]. This works but I have end up writing all the JWT validating code.
2. Implementing `ISecurityTokenValidator`

I can implement `ISecurityTokenValidator` to validate the token and using this in startup configuration something like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
                options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new JWTSecurityTokenValidator());
            });
```

And implemented my own class to validate the token.

```
public class JWTSecurityTokenValidator : ISecurityTokenValidator
{
    public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
    {
            // Implement the logic
    }
}
```

But again I end up doing heavy lifting. Also, I am not able to access the parameter "tenantId" in the ValidateToken.

3.Using `IssuerSigningKeyResolver`:
I can implement a delegate:

```
IEnumerable<SecurityKey> IssuerSigningKeyResolver(string token, SecurityToken securityToken, string kid, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
```

Again I don't's have access to the "tenantId" parameter  to choose the appropriate key.

Is there elegant solution to choosing `IssuerSigningKey` based on the parameter so that I don't need to write my own logic to validate JWT? Or only option is to go with first option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use DI to pass `IHttpContextAccessor` instance into your `JWTSecurityTokenValidator` and get value of `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` property.

From .Net Core 2.1 , you can register using extension :

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then in your custom `JWTSecurityTokenValidator` , modify to inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` :

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public JWTSecurityTokenValidator(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Modify the registration in `Startup.cs`  :

```
options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();

options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new JWTSecurityTokenValidator(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()));
```

So that in `ValidateToken` method ,you can read the parameter from `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` , according to how you pass the parameter , read it from query string or path :

```
public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
{
        var xx = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
        ........
}
```